# numpyでブロードキャストできない掛け算をforを使わず書く方法

Tags: python, numpy

最近数値計算をpythonでやり始めた者です。

例えば

```
A.shape #(3,5,5)
B.shape #(3,)
```

の形をもつA,Bについて

```
numpy.array([ A[i,:,:] * B[i] for i in range(3)]).reshape(5,5)
```

を計算したいのですが、この方法では規模が大きくなると遅いような気がしています。
この操作をより速く動くように書く方法はないものでしょうか？

Comment: `A * numpy.dstack(B).T` か `A * np.array([[B]]).T` でしょうか。しかし、これらがリスト内包表記よりも速いかどうか…？

Comment: 質問者です。書いていた計算内容がおかしいことに気づきました。最後のreshape(5,5)　は正しくは　reshape(3,5,5)　です。

Comment: `numpy.array([ A[i,:,:] ...` ですが、`np.array([a * b for a, b in zip(A, B)])` と書いてもよいかと思います。

Comment: metropolisさんのご提案を受けて試してみました。サイズ10000*7*7を10000回回した結果、A*np.array([[B]]).Tが一番早く15秒で、次が内包表記245秒、最後が

Comment: できれば結果を回答として書いて下さるとよいかと思います(その回答をご自身で承認することもできます)。

Comment: はじめてなもので、アドバイスありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Benchmarkerを使って試してみました。サイズ10000*7*7を10000回回した結果、

- `A*np.array([[B]]).T` が一番早く15秒‌​
- 次が内包表記の245秒（zipを使った場合が220秒）
- 最後が `A * np.dstack(B).T` で516秒でした。

とりあえず最も速かった `A*numpy.array([[B]])` を使おうと思います。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

別のやり方を説明を兼ねて。

基本的に質問者様が行いたいのは要素積だと思います。numpy.arrayの要素積はnp.multiplyもしくは*で行えますが、今の場合、配列の次元が違うのが厄介です。
np.multiplyは高次元の配列Aと一次元配列Bを掛けあわせた場合には、配列Aの最後の軸とBの要素積を行う仕様になっているようです。具体的には、C[i,j,k,l] = A[i,j,k,l] * B[l]のような積を返します。

今の場合はC[i,j,k] = A[i,j,k] * B[i]という積を行いたいので、そのためには以下の様な方法が可能だと思います（これ以外にも方法はあるかもしれません）。

1. 配列Bの次元をAと揃える。具体的には、B[i]に余分な軸を付け足すことでB[i,j,k]のような配列に変形してから要素積をとる。このやり方としては、np.newaxisを使う、Noneを使うなどがあります。前出の回答のnp.array([[B]])も実質的に同じことをしているはずです。（正確には、追加した軸の次元は１なので、AとBの配列は違う次元ですが、その辺はブロードキャストされて計算できるようです）
2. 転置をとることで、無理やりC[i,j,k] = A[i,j,k] * B[k]の形に落とす。
3. np.einsumを使う。この関数を使うと、任意のテンソルを任意の形で積をとることができるので、単純に実装するだけでいいなら万能だと思いますが、場合によっては速度の問題が起こるかもしれません。というのも、一般には配列の積はどの順番でループをとるかで（numpyを使う場合には明示的ループは書きませんが）、速度が変わるはずですが、この関数ではループの順番を明示的に指定できないからです。
4. 内包表記で具体的に書いてしまう。

くらいでしょうか。

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.rand(3,5,5)
B = np.random.rand(3)
#Method 1
print A*B[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]
print A*B[:,None,None]
print A * np.array([[B]]).T
print A*np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(B,1),1)
#Method 2
print (A.T * B).T
#Method 3
print np.einsum('ijk,i->ijk',A,B)
```

手元で速度を比べてみましたが、A.shape = (10000, 7, 7)では、方法1,2,3はほぼ同じで、方法4だけ10倍程度遅かったです。